# Will two dependent variables always have $\rho_{XY} \neq 0$?

Tags: probability, independence, correlation

Let's say I have two random variables $X$ and $Y$ and I know: 
$$f_{XY}(x,y) \neq f_X(x)f_Y(y)$$

will these two random variables always have a correlation coefficient $\rho_{XY} \neq 0$?

I am aware of the following fact:

*Independence implies $\rho_{XY} = 0$, but $\rho_{XY} = 0$ does not imply independence.*

I am struggling to find any relationship regarding the opposite.

That is, does dependence imply $\rho_{XY} \neq 0$? I know I can check whether 
$$E[XY] = E[X]E[Y]$$
but I am wondering if this is needed.

Thanks!

Comment: The fact that "$\rho_{XY}=0$ does not imply independence" is logically equivalent to "dependence does not imply $\rho_{XY}\ne 0$".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second part of the statement: 
*Independence implies $ρ_{XY}=0$, but $ρ_{XY}=0$ does not imply independence* 
is precisely equivalent to the fact that two dependent variables will NOT always have $ρ_{XY}\neq0$. It essentially says that there are variables that are not correlated but are not independent as well.

Comment: reversing the argument makes sense! Thanks!